# SYNTAX ERROR ON my account_settings.php

Tags: php

I am following an online tutorial. The problem is I am getting

> syntax error unexpected T_ELSE PHP white-space on the second last else.

I have tried to sort the PHP white-space using notepad++ but it's not going away.Am currently using PHP 8. Where might the error be originating from?

This is my account_settings.php page:

```
<?php
include( "header inc.php" ); 
if (!$user) {

}
else
{
 die ("You must be logged in to view this page!");
}
?>
<?php
$senddata = @$_POST['senddata'];

//Password variables
  $old_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,@$_POST['oldpassword']);
  $new_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,@$_POST['newpassword']);
  $repeat_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,@$_POST['newpassword2']);
if ($senddata) 
    //If the form is submitted..

     $password_query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($password_query)) {
        $db_password = $row['password'];

        //md5 the old password before we check if it matches
        $old_password_md5 = md5($old_password);

        //Check whether old password equals $db_password
        if ($old_password_md5 == $db_password) {
         //Continue Changing the users password ...
         //Check whether the 2 new passwords match
         if ($new_password == $repeat_password) {

            //md5 the new password before we add it to the database
            $new_password_md5 = md5($new_password);
           //Great! Update the users passwords!
           $password_update_query = $mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET password='$new_password_md5' WHERE username='$user'");
           echo "Success! Your password has been updated!"; 
           }
           }
           else
           {
            echo "Your two new passwords don't match!";
            }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "The old password is incorrect!";
                }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "";
                    }

?>
<h2>Edit your Account Settings below</h2>
<hr /> 
<form action="account_settings.php" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
<p>CHANGE YOUR PASSWORD:</p> <br />
Your Old Password: <input type="text" name="oldpassword" id="oldpassword" size="40"><br />
Your New Password: <input type="text" name="newpassword" id="newpassword" size="40"><br />
Repeat Password  : <input type="text" name="newpassword2" id="newpassword2" size="40"><br />

<hr />
<p>UPDATE YOUR PROFILE INFO:</p> <br />
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" size="40" value="<? echo $db_first_name; ?>"><br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" size="40" value="<? echo $db_last_name; ?>"><br />
About You: <textarea name="about you" id="about you" rows="7" cols="40"></textarea>

<hr />
<input type="submit" name="senddata" id="senddata" value="Update Information">
</form>
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly so it's easier to understand.

Comment: _Am currently using PHP 8_ How's that then?

Comment: Whats up with the negative votes??

Comment: Oh god he uses md5 to hash his passwords... Please migrate to the new PHP 5.5 Password Hashing API (there are even libraries for 5.3 and 5.4).

Comment: @CharlotteDunois thanks,i'll check it out

Comment: @Antony your code has some serious indentation issues. well, that of-course isn't causing the problem, but, it makes it difficult to read. think about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($senddata){

$password_query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($password_query)) {

 } 

 else{ 
 }
```

and at the end, the below mentioned else has no IF

```
 }
               else
            {
                echo "";
                }
```

Fixed it, try this one:

```
    <?php
    include( "header inc.php" ); 
    if (!$user) {

    }
    else
    {
     die ("You must be logged in to view this page!");
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    $senddata = @$_POST['senddata'];

    //Password variables
      $old_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,@$_POST['oldpassword']);
      $new_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,@$_POST['newpassword']);
      $repeat_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,@$_POST['newpassword2']);
    if ($senddata) {

        //If the form is submitted..

         $password_query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($password_query)) {
            $db_password = $row['password'];

            //md5 the old password before we check if it matches
            $old_password_md5 = md5($old_password);

            //Check whether old password equals $db_password
            if ($old_password_md5 == $db_password) {
             //Continue Changing the users password ...
             //Check whether the 2 new passwords match
             if ($new_password == $repeat_password) {

                //md5 the new password before we add it to the database
                $new_password_md5 = md5($new_password);
               //Great! Update the users passwords!
               $password_update_query = $mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET password='$new_password_md5' WHERE username='$user'");
               echo "Success! Your password has been updated!"; 
               }
               }
               else
               {
                echo "Your two new passwords don't match!";
                }
                }
    } 
                else
                {
                    echo "The old password is incorrect!";
                    }

    ?>
    <h2>Edit your Account Settings below</h2>
    <hr /> 
    <form action="account_settings.php" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
    <p>CHANGE YOUR PASSWORD:</p> <br />
    Your Old Password: <input type="text" name="oldpassword" id="oldpassword" size="40"><br />
    Your New Password: <input type="text" name="newpassword" id="newpassword" size="40"><br />
    Repeat Password  : <input type="text" name="newpassword2" id="newpassword2" size="40"><br />

    <hr />
    <p>UPDATE YOUR PROFILE INFO:</p> <br />
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" size="40" value="<? echo $db_first_name; ?>"><br />
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" size="40" value="<? echo $db_last_name; ?>"><br />
    About You: <textarea name="about you" id="about you" rows="7" cols="40"></textarea>

    <hr />
    <input type="submit" name="senddata" id="senddata" value="Update Information">
    </form>
```

Comment: can u help me with the new problem am having now?The page doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

The syntax errors was in `else` conditions.

Try

```
<?php
include ("header inc.php"); 
if (!$user)
{

}
else
{
    die ("You must be logged in to view this page!");
}

//Password variables
$old_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,@$_POST['oldpassword']);
$new_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,@$_POST['newpassword']);
$repeat_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,@$_POST['newpassword2']);

if(isset($_POST['senddata'])) 
{
    //If the form is submitted..
    $password_query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($password_query))
    {
        $db_password = $row['password'];

        //md5 the old password before we check if it matches
        $old_password_md5 = md5($old_password);

        //Check whether old password equals $db_password
        if ($old_password_md5 == $db_password)
        {
         //Continue Changing the users password ...
         //Check whether the 2 new passwords match
            if ($new_password == $repeat_password)
            {
                //md5 the new password before we add it to the database
                $new_password_md5 = md5($new_password);
                //Great! Update the users passwords!
                $password_update_query = $mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET password='$new_password_md5' WHERE username='$user'");
                echo "Success! Your password has been updated!"; 
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Your two new passwords don't match!";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "The old password is incorrect!";
        }
    }
}

?>
<h2>Edit your Account Settings below</h2>
<hr /> 
<form action="account_settings.php" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
<p>CHANGE YOUR PASSWORD:</p> <br />
Your Old Password: <input type="text" name="oldpassword" id="oldpassword" size="40"><br />
Your New Password: <input type="text" name="newpassword" id="newpassword" size="40"><br />
Repeat Password  : <input type="text" name="newpassword2" id="newpassword2" size="40"><br />

<hr />
<p>UPDATE YOUR PROFILE INFO:</p> <br />
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" size="40" value="<? echo $db_first_name; ?>"><br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" size="40" value="<? echo $db_last_name; ?>"><br />
About You: <textarea name="about you" id="about you" rows="7" cols="40"></textarea>

<hr />
<input type="submit" name="senddata" id="senddata" value="Update Information">
</form>
```

Comment: @Antony please accept my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: Thanks Hassaan,bt the new problem is,when i try to change password on the form,nothin happens

Comment: ,the error comes back if i use ur edited answer bt wen i use ur 1st answer it's not there so am stickin with the 1st

Comment: @Antony please use my fresh answer now.

Comment: I have,the error is gone bt the form's not working.When i change password and press enter/update info it just reloads